# Reading file in PCL, Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want read as well as create a file in SD card from a PCL in Xamarin. 
When i tried to use `System.IO`, It is not giving me the `File` class to create or open a file from PCL. 
Is there any method for accessing the file ? 
My file (txt file with JSON Data) will be residing in the SD card of an android device.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards

VK Mallaya

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the implementation of `System.IO` file classes is different between iOS and Android what you will need to do is define an interface, e.g. `IFileSystem` in your PCL and then implement that interface in both your iOS project and your Android project where you can call into the native implementations.

Use dependency injection to inject the appropriate `IFileSystem` into your shared application classes implemented in PCL assemblies.

Comment: Thank you @ian Mercer 
i have implemented and i returned the stream to PCL where i can process the data.